# How do I implement a single sign-on for different ColdFusion applications running on the same server?

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, session-variables, single-sign-on, coldfusion-9

I have multiple CF applications running on the same server under the same domain name. One of them, let's call it **Portal**, is intended to be the single sign-on for the other applications, which let's call **Atlas** and **P-Body**. Normally you would set some variables in the `session` scope to handle login info:

```
function Login()
{
    session.auth = structNew();
    session.auth.isLoggedIn = true;
    session.auth.id = GetCurrentUserId();
}
```

But the session scope is only shared within **one** application, not the entire server. This means that any user who logs into **Portal** will stay logged in, but if they try to navigate to **Atlas** or **P-Body**, they will have to sign in again.

In this case, how would I 'share' the session scope so that all the applications on a server can get access to it? The only way I've been able to come up with is to use **client variables** and set a data store so that it's shared between applications. Then the code becomes:

```
function Login()
{
    client.auth = structNew();
    client.auth.isLoggedIn = true;
    client.auth.id = GetCurrentUserId();
}

function Logout()
{
    structDelete(client, "auth");
}
```

The thing to watch out for here is that, because the client variable is not cleared on session end, we have to manually clear it in the `OnSessionEnd` handler.

Is this the best way of handling single sign-on in ColdFusion? If so, are there any drawbacks to using the **client variable**, or pitfalls to watch out for?

**Update:** I just tested the client variable method and it looks like only the `hitcount`, `timecreated`, `lastvisit`, and `urltoken` are shared between applications, so I'm back to square 1.

Comment: Are all of your applications under a single domain (www.yourdomains.com/appname)? If so, you can use the Session scope, but each Application.cfc/cfm needs to specify the same Application name (this.name or the name attribute in `cfapplication`). If they're on different domains (even subdomains) then you're going to have to use cookies or an SSO solution as Jason suggested.

Comment: They're on the same domain (no sub-domain), but in different folders. I'm not sure if we can declare the same `this.name` for all the applications, but it seems like a somewhat sub-optimal solution.

Comment: It's not suboptimal, it's the exact right solution. If they all authenticate against the same systems, and are all on the same domain, aren't they all (in the end) part of the same application? As soon as you make their application names the same, then they'll share session and application scopes, and your SSO problem goes away provided that they all use the same checks and auth logic. It's seamless (after you review your code to make sure it will work :-)

Comment: The only reason I can think of that that would be a "sub-optimal solution" is if there would be Application or session scope conflicts between the two applications. Do they all have App or session scope variables with the same names (used for different purposes)?

Comment: @Dan: I see your point, but as Jason pointed out, there -may- be application or session scope conflicts (I'm just not sure at this point). However, I believe that they should be considered independent applications that may or may not be on the same domain/sub-domain, so I'm guessing that this means a true SSO solution is the only way to go.

Comment: Well there's what they "should be considered" and then there's getting the job done :). Matching application names could fix the issue, but yes, as Jason and I pointed out, you do have to make sure you're not clashing scopes. I do this all the time when I roll 3rd party apps under my main apps, and then it does require a bit of tweaking to make them all play nice together. But *far* less than dealing with a "true SSO" solution and all the pain they can bring to the party :)

Comment: Point taken, Dan :). Thanks for the advice. This is all forward-looking at this point, so when it becomes a real requirement, we'll look at the trade-offs of both methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as the answer given new information.

**Caveat**

---

Ensure that all of the applications have either a) unique application scope names for persistent variables, or b) all application scope variables for the same purpose are named the same.

---

Alright, with that out of the way, if all of your applications are on a single domain in subfolders, then change `this.name` or the `name` attribute of `cfapplication` the same, and all of the applications will share the same `session` and `application` scope variables. This will ensure that if you use `session.loggedin` in one app, that same `session.loggedin` variable will be available to all applications with the same name under that domain.

You just have to test carefully to make sure that you don't end up using `Application.LoginService` in Portal for your `LoginService.cfc`, and `Application.LoginService` in Atlas for either a different `LoginService.cfc`, or a completely different purpose altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Single Sign On (SSO) is not an easy thing to do and there are several very expensive products out there that help to prove that.

Fortunately, there are some free OSS projects out there are well.

There are also many other considerations with SSO that make its implementation difficult, like how do you handle it when a user clicks "Log off" on one of the sites?  Do you log them out of all of them? If so, how?

If you want to do SSO right, you need to look at using an SSO solution, like Shibboleth (FOSS), or Atlassian Crowd (Reasonably priced commercial solution).

If you do not have the resources to use an SSO product like those above, then you will end up hacking around the current security restrictions that make SSO so difficult.

Comment: I understand that SSO is hard to do correctly, if you wanted a true cross-domain SSO solution. However, in our case, our use case is too simple to warrant implementing an OSS framework, and the pages are all part of a single domain.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close with the client variable solution.

Set up a remote database that all applications can speak to, either through the DSN, or through another single point of entry (ie. a WebService)

Decide on a common way to identify users across all your applications (ie. come up with your own unique sessionid, perhaps based off of CFID/CFTOKEN, CreateUUID(), or anything else you can guarantee is unique).

Build your authentication process so that when someone authenticates somewhere in your application farm...anywhere...that unique sessionid is stored to the remote database.

Pass that unique sessionid from app to app. Perhaps append it to your hyperlinks, or store it in client variables (cookies) that you mentioned earlier.

Finally, in your application logic that checks to see if someone is authenticated, before forcing them to login again...use their client variables (or the passed unique sessionid) to check back with the remote datasource, and auth them if you have found/verified it.

This is an oversimplification, but is the foundation for SSO, and should get you thinking in the right direction.

PS: Keep all your applications on the same domain, if possible (xx.mysite.com, yy.mysite.com) so that your client vars (cookies) can be set to be domain-specific, allowing them to traverse the application farm as you need them to.

Answer (score -1):

Use the server scope.  It is shared across applications.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fdb.html

Comment: Oh, and don't use client variables. For the many, many reasons why you can refer to this excellent blog article.  http://dopefly.com/pages/ColdFusionClientVariablesFinalNail.cfm

Comment: If the applications live on the same domain you could also write domain cookies.

Comment: I don't think the server scope is a good choice for storing user data. The server scope is a shared scope that is not specific to users. So not only would you need to manage keeping that data separate, but you would also have to do your own session management.

Comment: If the apps like on the same domain you *can* use domain cookies, but I believe that ColdFusion will still create separate sessions for each application. So unless all of the apps live on the same server *and* share an application name, that may not work.

Comment: 100% agreed on the server scope.  I have no idea what I was smoking.  I saw "scope across applications" and thought server scope without thinking it through.  It makes no sense to store user specific information there.  I wish I could down vote my own answer.

Comment: For domain cookies, yes each app will have its own session, but each app could also read the cookie.  That said, cookies have their own issues, not least of all the security implications of storing data in a cookie.  Dan's answer seems to be the best approach, to ensure that all applications share a name.